# i have a question about order&limit of mysql

Tags: mysql, database

- os: windows10
- mysql version: 8.0.22

there is my DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_user` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uniq_show_id` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT '',
  `mobile` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT '',
  `items_grids` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `currency` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `internal_currency` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `exp` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `phy` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pre_restore_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `level` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `shadow_rock` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `formation_id` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `supporting_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `red_diamonds` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `invite_code` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_show_id` (`uniq_show_id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_username` (`username`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_nickname` (`nickname`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_invitecode` (`invite_code`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=223623 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

i just executed a sample sql:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM tb_user WHERE id  > 125 LIMIT 10;
```

there is the execution plan:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | tb_user | NULL | range | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | NULL | 110328 | 100 | Using where; Using index |

as you can see there scaned 110328 rows

if i adding the clause `order by`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM tb_user WHERE id  > 125  ORDER BY uniq_show_id LIMIT 10;
```

there is the execution plan of sql above:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | tb_user | NULL | index | PRIMARY | uniq_show_id | 402 | NULL | 20 | 50 | Using where; Using index |

as you can see, it only scaned 20 rows

what is the reason make it different when i just adding the clause `order by`?

thanks for your answer!

Comment: Without ORDER BY the index can be used only for the condition processing, and server retrieves all matched rows then selects needed rows amount. With ORDER BY this index is used for both condition processing and sorting, so the process may be stopped after needed amount of rows is collected. 20 (not 10) examined rows may be defined by the rows amount per index page.